# Odd type syntax used with isinstance()

Tags: python

I was recently tasked with migrating a bunch of existing python 2.7 scripts to python 3.x, and noticed a statement in one of the scripts that I don't quite understand:

```
if isinstance(some_variable, (list,)):
   # ...
```

At first I thought the `(,)` syntax might be a way to express a partially typed tuple, but that doesn't seem to be the case:

```
>>> isinstance(([],123), (list,))
False
```

Looking at the calling code, I found that the only argument values ever passed as `some_variable` were lists, so I tested:

```
>>> isinstance([], (list,))
True
```

So why would you use `(list,)` instead of just `list` with `isinstance()`?

I *suspect* that there might be other (list-like?) types for which the call to `isinstance()` would return `True`, but I don't have the requisite python experience to think of what it be :)

Comment: Looks like either automatic tool output, or someone copying and modifying code without understanding it. There's no reason to use `(list,)` instead of `list` there.

Comment: You find this version in *python2* or *python3*?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM in python2, but it appears to behave the same in python3

Comment: It could also be the result of editing code that *used* to check multiple types, and the edit simply kept the tuple to keep the diff minimal.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance): *"Return `True` if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, [...]. __If classinfo is a tuple of type objects__ (or recursively, other such tuples), __return True if object is an instance of any of the types__. If classinfo is not a type or tuple of types and such tuples, a TypeError exception is raised."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) can get a type OR a tuple of types as the second argument.

`(list,)` is a tuple with 1 entry only. In the case that you have only one type to compare against you dont have to use `tuple`

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, I just noticed `isinstance("", (list, str)) and isinstance([], (list, str))` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is `(list,)` tuple with one element and like this `list` and for your example :

```
>>> isinstance(([],123), (list,))
False 

>>> isinstance(([],123), (tuple,))
True

>>> isinstance(([],123), tuple)
True
```

if you want check `isinstance` do with `map` like below:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x : isinstance(x , (list,)), ([],123)))
[True, False]

>>> all(map(lambda x : isinstance(x , (list,)), ([],123)))
False

>>> any(map(lambda x : isinstance(x , (list,)), ([],123)))
True
```